# "doesn't look like a valid pdf file, couldnt find xref section"

Tags: pdf

This is the notice I received when I tried extracting a font from a PDF using font forge (a font I own) using "extract font from pdf" option.

I'm not so well versed in all these concepts, can someone please enlighten me on what this means, why it is so and how it can be fixed.

I tried googling it but I couldn't find anything that seems to solve my problem, I don't even think I was able to start understanding what this is.

(thank you for regarding  my ignorance)

Comment: Please share more details. Where does that claim come from? What kind of "problem" are you facing?

Comment: I am trying to extract a font from a pdf using font forge (a font I own but I guess it got lost when I got a new computer), when I try opening the pdf with font forge "extract font" this is what I get.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should contain the code you are using for that extraction, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the file you try to open (?) as a PDF file is actually badly formatted.

You see, file format for a specific kind of file - PDF in this case - has some criteria. In particular, the xref table contains some references of objects, so the PDF reader can read them by their reference when needed.

So, a PDF reader starts reading the PDF file by reading the xref table and when that's successfully done, then you can actually navigate inside the file without having to wait for the PDF reader to load the whole file into memory. Now, the error message you have states that the xref section is missing, hence your file is badly formatted. Read more here: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2011/05/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-%E2%80%93-pdf-xref-tables-explained/

Comment: the file can open fine, and everything (I think) about the pdf works, just when I try to open it in font forge (to extract a font that I own ...) this is the notice that I get.

Comment: and thank you for the reference, it is definitely very informative!

Comment: @Zjamkeh it is because some PDF readers might decide to load the whole file and generate the references at runtime. The file is still badly formatted, but the reader walks around the issue. If my answer helped you understand the issue and possibly solve it, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Zjamkeh  Indeed, just because a PDF opens in a PDF viewer doesn't mean it is ok - PDF viewers have a tendency to ignore or fix numerous errors under the hood. Please share a link to your PDF for analysis.

Comment: I am reading PDF specification and wondering why in heavens name I need cross reference section aka xref. And I have a similar PDF measuring 294kb that has no cross reference table. But it has startxref which should be the beginning of cross reference section. Probably they made a mistake while creating the PDF. At any rate, application meant to render documents: HTML, XML, XHMTL, PDF, RTF, DOC, SVG etc will always have some tolerance. Especially that certain formats like RTF have poor documentation.

Comment: Note that the pdf document I mentioned has the /Linearized token; so I am not sure if this allows exceptions for the version it uses. Note that PDF viewers of smaller version may have problems with PDF documents of later version.